# Reload the content of a div afer regular interval of time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I want to reload the content of a div (Recent_updates) after regular interval of time. I've used the following javascript code

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        $('#Recent_updates').fadeOut("slow").load('Recent_updates.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 60000);
```

Recent_updates.php

```
<?php
include("include/connect.php");
include("library/paginator.php");
?>
<div style="text-align:right;">
    <?
    $query = "select * from settings";
    $tab = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($tab);
    $item_no = $row['items_to_show'];
    $scroll = $row['scroll_interval'];

    $online_paginate = new Paginator;
    $online_paginate->sql = "select * from recent_updates where status='Active' and picture1!='' and selling_method!='want_it_now' and selling_method!='ads' and bid_starting_date <= now() and expire_date>=now() order by item_id desc"; // sql statement
    $online_paginate->rows_on_page = $item_no;
    $results = $online_paginate->get_page_result(); // result set
    $num_rows = $online_paginate->get_page_num_rows(); // number of records in result set
    $nav_links = $online_paginate->navigation("&nbsp; | &nbsp;"); // the navigation links (define a CSS class
    ?>
</div>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr bgcolor="#d79196" class="detail9txt">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="len">
    <td align="center" width="20%"><b>Picture</b> </td>
    <td width="30%" align="center"><b>Name / Responses</b> </td>
    <td width="50%" align="center"><b>Description</b> </td>
</tr><tr style="height:10px;"><td></td></tr>
<?
if ($num_rows > 0) {
    while ($bestsellers_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        $temp = $bestsellers_fetch['item_id'];
        $sql = "SELECT count(`user_id`) as response FROM `watch_list` where `item_id`=$temp group by `item_id`";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);

        $response = mysql_fetch_row($res);

        $counttop = $counttop + 1;
        if (!empty($bestsellers_fetch['sub_title']))
            $item_subtitle1 = $bestsellers_fetch['sub_title'];
        else
            $item_subtitle1 = substr($bestsellers_fetch['item_title'], 0, 20);
        $item_title1 = substr($bestsellers_fetch['item_title'], 0, 40)
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="tr_botborder" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="20%" align="center"><div align="center"><a href="detail.php?item_id=<?= $bestsellers_fetch['item_id']; ?>" class="bestsellerstxt"><img src="thumbnail/<?= $bestsellers_fetch['picture1']; ?>" alt="" width="79" height="70" border="0" /></a></div></td>
            <td class="tr_botborder" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="30%" align="center"><div align="center"><span class="bestsellerstxt"><a href="detail.php?item_id=<?= $bestsellers_fetch['item_id']; ?>" class="bestsellerstxt"><?= $item_subtitle1; ?> <?= $item_title1; ?></a><br/><?php if ($response[0] != '') { ?><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#336666;" href="detail.php?item_id=<?= $bestsellers_fetch['item_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $response[0] . '&nbsp;responses'; ?></a> <?php } else { ?><span style="color:#666666;"><?php
            echo '0&nbsp;responses';
        }
        ?></span></span></td>
            <td class="tr_botborder" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="50%" align="center"><div align="center"><span class="bestsellerstxt"><a href="#" class="bestsellerstxt"><?= html_entity_decode($bestsellers_fetch['detailed_descrip']); ?></a></span></td>
        </tr>

        <?
        if ($counttop != 2) {

        }
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <tr><td height="148" align="center" class="featxt">No Items Available</td></tr>
    <?
}
?>
</table>
<div style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $nav_links; ?></div>
```

This code is working fine all browsers except IE. 
When I go to the page on my ie9 and not do anything after a few (5-8) minutes the page just goes blank.

Comment: I can't really help with your issue, but just as a general tip, it's better practice use nested `setTimeout` calls instead of `setInterval` (http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts), although with your 60 second interval, it shouldn't really be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been through this...Actually the Load fail because IE strictly validates the HTML returned. so make sure `Recent_updates.php` returns valid html

Comment: Yaa.. Recent_updates.php returns valid html. I've added contents of that page in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for IE9 but I had this type of issue in older versions of IE. That browser has the bad habit of opening persistant connections to the server and most servers (if not all) have a limit in the amount of open connections per user.
Knowing you have an interval of 1min and that a persistant connection timesout after 5min, just count and you see why...