# Refresh a PHP required file within a specific intervals

Tags: javascript, php, html, reload, ajax-polling

I tried these:

```
    <div id="result">
<table>
<?php require('newses.php'); ?>
</table>
</div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
 function autoRefresh_div()
 {
      $("#result").load("load.html");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
  }

  setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 1000); // refresh div after 5 secs
            </script>
```

But it didn't worked for me.
Please visit these pages:

[Reload the content of a div afer regular interval of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700017/reload-the-content-of-a-div-afer-regular-interval-of-time)

http://devzone.co.in/automatically-refresh-html-page-div-specific-time-interval/

Comment: Your refresh time out is at 1 minute not 5 seconds.

Comment: check in console whats the error .on my side it is reloading

Comment: @Sand how to set 1 second?

Comment: @Abhishek does it really work? Can I really reload a server side script,by using client side script?

Comment: instead of loading load.html , im doing this approach and its working fine
   "window.location.href =http://localhost/PhpProject1/chek.php"

window.location.reload refresh the browser client side but fetch data from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self.
There was a small problem in my code.
I was wanting my page to include newses.php file in my page, and refresh the same file (newses.php) after every 1 seconds. The JavaScript code had a small problem. The refresh page's code name was load.html,so that the browser tries to load **load.html** page after 1 sec of first web page loading.
When I changed refresh code from  `$("#result").load("load.html");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds` to  `$("#result").load("newses.php");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds`, my page became totally working correctly.
Here is the edited code.

function autoRefresh_div() { $("#result").load("newses.php");// a function which will load data from other file after x seconds } setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 1000); // refresh div after 5 secs

Answer (score 1):

```js
function autoRefresh_div() {
  $("#result").html('<object data="https://static.pexels.com/photos/17679/pexels-photo.jpg"/>'); // a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
  alert('working');
}

setInterval(autoRefresh_div, 5000); // refresh div after 5 sec
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

This will load the page ever 5.